# Set background image from picture library

Tags: c#, xaml, background, windows-phone-8, grid

i have to set programmatically a background of a grid with an image taken from the picture library (NO assets folder of the app)...

I have tried with this code

```
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();

Picture picture = library.Pictures[rnd.Next(0, 7)];
string path = picture.GetPath();

BackgroundImg.ImageSource = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("ms-appdata:///Local/" + picture.Name, UriKind.Absolute) };

//BackgroundImg.ImageSource = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute) };
```

The code works if the pict is taken from the assets folder in the project, so i think the error is the uri!

Can anyone help me please?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved in this way:

```
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
Picture picture = library.Pictures[rnd.Next(0, library.Pictures.Count - 1)];

BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapimage.SetSource(picture.GetImage());
BackgroundImg.ImageSource = bitmapimage;
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use StorageFile instead of   "ms-appdata:///local/".

try with this method it works fine for me.

```
        public void setBackgroundImage(String pictureName)
       {

        using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (var stream = storage.OpenFile(pictureName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapimage.SetSource(stream);
                BackgroundImg.ImageSource = bitmapimage;

            }
        }

    }
```

and then you call it

`setBackgroundImage(picture.Name);`

*Note in Windows Phone 8 you can still use isolated storage and Silverlight Uri.

Comment: It seems does not work... I receive an exception "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream."

Comment: I think the problem is that the image is notf found... perhaps i should move in the right folder (picture library)